# Should there be a possessive in "like that of a peacock('s)"?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, possessives, comparison, apostrophe

> 1. She has great charm, even like that of a **peacock's**
> 2. She has great charm, even like that of a **peacock**

The comparison is not between the lady and the peacock. It is between the charms of the lady and the peacock. I have a feeling there has to be an "'s" and so (1) is the correct way of writing it. I am mostly confused when it comes to sentence structures such as this. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence (1) is incorrect. "*peacock's*" is a possessive form, but nothing is possessed in (1).

> (2) She has great charm, even like that of a peacock

is correct. Or the same thought could be expressed as

> (3) She has great charm, much like a peacock's charm.

or one could shorten this to

> (3A) She has great charm, much like a peacock's.

In general one will use "*of X*" or  or "*X's*" but not both together in this sort of construction.

> - It has great {A}, like that of an X. [image: Green check mark, indicating a correct form]
> - It has great {A}, like an X's. [image: Green check mark, indicating a correct form]

But not

> It has great {A}, like that of an X's. [image: Red X, indicating an incorrect form]